# How to run uf2 program file without USB connection

Tags: makecode

I'm developping a little program that should watch at the download folder and automatically transfert UF2 file from https://makecode.mindstorms.com using a bluetooth connection and execute it. I'm using MonoBrick for that (http://www.monobrick.dk).

I don't understand how this UF2 file work. When I upload this file to the lego Mindstorms through an USB connection it automatically start (what is not very convenient as the cable is still connected).
But, when doing the same process with my code or using EV3Explorer (https://github.com/c0pperdragon/EV3Basic/tree/master/EV3Explorer) nothing happen. I can see the file with the file explorer on Windows but not directly on the Lego Mindstorms Brick.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to bricks.stackexchange.com